# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\classes\Post' not found

Tags: php, mysql

I get this error messages.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/HGy93.jpg

Error Message in the browser:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in /storage/ssd3/467/16218467/public_html/migs/header.php on line 6

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Class 'App\classes\Post' not found in /storage/ssd3/467/16218467/public_html/migs/header.php:7 Stack trace: #0 /storage/ssd3/467/16218467/public_html/migs/index.php(1): require_once() #1 {main} thrown in /storage/ssd3/467/16218467/public_html/migs/header.php on line

**Header.php file:**

```
<?php
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
use App\classes\Post;
use App\classes\Site;
$ob = Site::display();
$siteData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ob);
#$post = Post::showActivelPost();
$populer = Post::showPopulerlPost();
$page = explode('/',$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
$page = end($page);
$title = '';
if($page == 'login.php'){
    $title = 'Home';
}
elseif ($page == 'contact.php'){
    $title = 'Contact';
}
?>
```

**index.php file:**

```
<?php require_once 'header.php';
use App\classes\Helper;
?>
```

**vendor/autoload.php file**

```
<?php

// autoload.php @generated by Composer

require_once __DIR__ . '/composer/autoload_real.php';

return ComposerAutoloaderInit395f5b340c36bfceaef3eb81b290035a::getLoader();
```

Comment: the error seems pretty clear, the PHP interpreter cannot find the class. You sure your including it correctly?

Comment: Like @GiacomoM says it cannot find the class, so locate that class and ensure the paths are correct. Perhaps a capital `C` for `classes`?

Comment: yes i included it correctly

Comment: Check the `Post` class. Are you setting the namespace correctly?

Comment: Yes @El_Vanja  I set it correctly

Comment: To fix the first error remove the line `$siteData = mysqli_fetch_assoc($ob);`. $ob is clearly a boolean and you are not using mysqli functions in your code